# How can I find the matching part of the array with the values in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a shopping cart system for my website.

The System works as:

- System fetches the Shopping Cart string and splits it into an array with ",".
- System checks for the matching part inside of the array.
- If the system finds the product; It prints "Product Found!"
- If Not; the system prints "Product Not Found!"

I did this but the system always prints "Product Not Found!", how can I solve it?

The array that I use `{1234567890,#000000,XL,1,100,1234567899,#000000,XL,2,100}`

Array Pattern is ProductID,SelectedColor,SelectedSize,Product Quantity,Price.

```js
var ShoppingCartArray = ShoppingCartValue.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < ShoppingCartArray.length; i = i + 5) {
    var cartProductID = ShoppingCartArray[i];
    var cartColor = ShoppingCartArray[i + 1];
    var cartSize = ShoppingCartArray[i + 2];
    var cartQuantity = parseInt(ShoppingCartArray[i + 3]);
    var cartPrice = ShoppingCartArray[i + 4];

    console.log("Cart Product ID:", cartProductID);
    console.log("Cart Color:", cartColor);
    console.log("Cart Size:", cartSize);
    console.log("Cart Quantity:", cartQuantity);
    console.log("Cart Price:", cartPrice);

    if (
        cartProductID === ProductID &&
        cartColor === SelectedColor &&
        cartSize === SelectedSize &&
        cartPrice === Price
    ) {
        console.log("Product Found !");

        var ProductQuantity = cartQuantity;

        console.log("Quantity:", ProductQuantity);
    } else {
        console.log("Product Not Found !");
    }
}
```

Comment: What values are `ProductID`, `SelectedColor`, `SelectedSize` and `Price`? Does values types matches?

Comment: @Justinas they are all String.

Comment: Are you sure `ProductID`, `SelectedColor`, `SelectedSize` and `Price` are not empty values?

Comment: If the initial string `ShoppingCartValue` is indeed `{1234567890,#000000,XL,1,100,1234567899,#000000,XL,2,100}` then the first `cartProductID` will contain the `{` and the last `cartPrice` will contain the `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if type of `ProductID` is same to `cartProductID` or convert both to string variables:

```
cartProductID.toString() === ProductID.toString()
```

Comment: I did bu I get the same problem.